# ASP .NET MVC - Windows Authentication - Formulário de Autenticação Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, autenticação

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação ASP .NET MVC cujas permissões de acesso serão gerenciadas a partir de parâmetros definidos para os usuários no **Active Directory (AD)**.

Para a busca destes dados do **AD** desenvolvi métodos que enviam o UserName do usuário (no nosso caso uma matrícula) e retorna os dados completos (departamento, nome completo, etc.).

A autenticação é realizada através do *Windows Authentication*, e o UserName eu busco através do seguinte código no método **Session_Start** da classe **Global.asax**:

```
var matricula = (Request.IsLocal && HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled) ? Environment.UserName : User.Identity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
```

O meu web.config é configurado da seguinte forma:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

A questão é que mesmo utilizando a *Autenticação Windows* o sistema abre volta e meia um formulário de autenticação gerado pelo browser, no qual o usuário digita seu user e password para que ocorra a re-autenticação na rede da empresa.

Obs: Na empresa utilizamos basicamente o **Mozilla Firefox** e o **IE** (o *Chrome* é usado em apenas algumas unidades/filiais). Necessitamos que a regra de autenticação sirva para ambos navegadores. Os testes que fiz foram no **Firefox**.

Porém, considerando se tratar uma aplicação na intranet da empresa, as regras de negócio e o fato do usuário já ter efetuado seu login na estação e estar autenticado no *domínio* da empresa, achamos que tal necessidade de autenticação não deveria ser necessária.

Considerando esta situação, solicito ajuda para esclarecer se há algum erro de configuração no projeto que está ocasionando esta abertura esporádica do formulário de autenticação do Browser ou se falta alguma configuração.

Comment: Qual o navegador você está utilizando para os testes usando o *Windows Authentication*?

Comment: Boa tarde. Aqui usam Firefox e IE em toda empresa, então o sistema deve rodar com estas regras nos dois navegadores. Os testes foram feitos com o Firefox. Vou atualizar a pergunta com esta info.

Answer (score 1):

Como você não precisa de uma tela de login, basta você criar um projeto ASP.NET MVC e mudar o tipo de autenticação, para `Windows Authentication`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando você executar o Código, você terá o domínio/usuário através do código abaixo na View criada pelo ASP.NET:

```
@User.Identity.Name
```

**Acessar o User no Controller**

Basta usar o código abaixo, que você terá o usuário logado:

```
var User = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
```

**[Edit]**

Baseado na edição da sua pergunta, como você quer apenas remover o pop-up de login, você deve fazer algumas configurações no IIS:

- Desativar a autenticação anonima(quando abrir as configurações do seu site, está em Autenticação).
- E ainda em autenticação, você deve habilitar a autenticação do windows
- E o servidor do IIS e o cliente devem estar no mesmo domínio.

O resto está ok.

Comment: Olá Cassio. Agradeço a sua resposta, porém como ressaltei na questão postada, eu já conheço a solução do Windows Authentication e a utilizo em meus projetos, sendo a questão justamente o fato de ainda que usando esta opção integrada de autenticação o navegador abre um formulário para o usuário se autenticar com a login e senha da rede Windows. A minha questão é justamente se há uma opção de usar autenticação anônima e pegar os dados do usuário ou então uma forma de que o Windows Authentication utilizasse o login do usuário na estação e não dados de autenticação do browser.

Comment: Arthur, poderia me mostrar como ta sua <system.web> do web.config

Comment: Olá Cassio, reformulei a pergunta para ficar mais clara a minha dúvida quanto ao formulário de autenticação utilizando a opção Windows Authentication e coloquei o <system.web>.

Comment: editei minha resposta